# Windows batch script - extracting variable number of parameters

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, argument-passing

In a Windows batch script, I want to pass a variable number of arguments, then use the first n-1 of these to build a new variable, and the nth argument as another variable

so if I enter `script.cmd arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`, I want to be able to do

```
set newvariable1="arg1 arg2 arg3"
set newvariable2="arg4"
```

and if I enter `script.cmd arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6`

```
set newvariable1="arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5"
set newvariable2="arg6"
```

where the arguments are alphanumeric strings

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "newvariable1="
set "newvariable2="
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set newvariable1=!newvariable1! !newvariable2!
   set newvariable2=%%a
)
set newvariable1="%newvariable1:~2%"
set newvariable2="%newvariable2%"

echo newvariable1=%newvariable1%
echo newvariable2=%newvariable2%
```

Comment: Could you upvote this answer as "Useful" and later select it as "Best Answer"? (when you have enough rep. to do so)